# In leaflet, how to plot points at fixed distance

Tags: r, geolocation, leaflet

How do you plot several points by fixed distance in leaflet?
I have a fixed lat/long point, and from this point I would like to continuously plot several points towards certain direction(e.g. 180 degree).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destination](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#destination) from [L.GeometryUtil](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil)

```
var latlng = L.GeometryUtil.destination(latlng, heading, distance)
```

Comment: Thank you, however I am afraid that I would like to do it by R, not js.